# OpenCV error using PCL + ROS + Kinect

Tags: opencv, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working with PCL, ROS to use my kinect, I got an error when I use the following code:

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
 #include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>
 #include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
 #include <ros/ros.h>
 #include <boost/foreach.hpp>
 #include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
 #include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
using namespace std;
ros::Publisher pub;
typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB rgbpoint;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloudrgb;
typedef cloudrgb::Ptr cloudrgbptr;
void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud)
{
cloudrgbptr PC (new cloudrgb());
cloudrgbptr PC_filtered (new cloudrgb());
pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud, *PC); //Now you can process this PC using the pcl functions
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_filtered;
// Perform the actual filtering
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> sor ;
sor.setInputCloud (PC);
sor.setLeafSize (0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
sor.filter (*PC_filtered);
//Convert the pcl cloud back to rosmsg
pcl::toROSMsg(*PC_filtered, cloud_filtered);
//Set the header of the cloud
cloud_filtered.header.frame_id = cloud->header.frame_id;
// Publish the data
//You may have to set the header frame id of the cloud_filtered also
pub.publish (cloud_filtered);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "test_pcl_ros");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("camera/rgb/points", 1, cloud_cb);
pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/camera/rgb/david", 1);
ros::spin();
}
```

And use the following commands:

$ roscore

$ rosrun openni_camera openni_node

$ rosrun my_pcl_test run_test input:=/camera/rgb/points

$ rosrun pcl_ros convert_pointcloud_to_image input:=/camera/rgb/david output:=/camera/rgb/david_img

Until that line everything works fine,the output is published as a Type: sensor_msgs/Image, but then I want to output the image in a window doing:

$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/david_img

I get this error:

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 646
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:646: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat

Any clue why is this happening, thanks in advance!

David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33223/opencv-error-using-pcl-+-ros-+-kinect/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-09**:
...the output is an image? You're publishing a PointCloud2. That's not an Image. Is there a typo in your question?

**Comment by [lfelipesv](https://answers.ros.org/users/10721/lfelipesv/) on 2014-01-28**:
I'm with this problem now, someone know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

'Formats' are not compatible.

- **Format 1:** cvArr requires the first 4 bytes to determine what data the matrix (or rather a cvMat object) would have. The 1st four bytes contain a rather important datatype information like CV_32FC1, CV_8UC1. Also, OpenCV is rather sensitive to RBG, BGR. Your error is caused since the first 4 bytes are of nothing OpenCV can understand
- **Format 2:** image_view takes image parameter, BUT that is a **topic, not a file**

So, OpenCV is saying it can't understand whatever you are trying to do, but the actual error lies in the fact that you are subscribed to an empty topic.

---

Originally posted by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) with karma: 105 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0